# Airflow - GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator does not render templated source_objects

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

The [documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_bq.html) states that the `source_objects` argument takes templated values. However when I try the following:

```
gcs_to_bq_op = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id=name,
    bucket='gdbm-public',
    source_objects=['entity/{{ ds_nodash }}.0.{}.json'.format(filename)],
    destination_project_dataset_table='dbm_public_entity.{}'.format(name),
    schema_fields=schema,
    source_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
    create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    max_bad_records=0,
    allow_jagged_rows=True,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='my_gcp_conn',
    bigquery_conn_id='my_gcp_conn',
    delegate_to=SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
    dag=dag
    )
```

I receive the error message:
`Exception: BigQuery job failed. Final error was: {u'reason': u'notFound', u'message': u'Not found: URI gs://gdbm-public/entity/{ ds_nodash }.0.GeoLocation.json'}.`

I found an [example](https://github.com/alexvanboxel/airflow-gcp-examples/blob/master/dags/bigquery.py) where the `{{ ds_nodash }}` variable is used in the same way. So I'm not sure why this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that calling `.format` on the string is causing one set of the double braces to be removed:

```
>>> 'entity/{{ ds_nodash }}.0.{}.json'.format(filename)
'entity/{ ds_nodash }.0.foobar.json'
```

You need to escape the braces that you want to be in the string by doubling them:

```
>>> 'entity/{{{{ ds_nodash }}}}.0.{}.json'.format(filename)
'entity/{{ ds_nodash }}.0.foobar.json'
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is exactly like Dustin has described, calling `.format` on the string is causing one set of the double braces to be removed. However, instead of doubling the bracket which is 1 solution:

```
'entity/{{{{ ds_nodash }}}}.0.{}.json'.format(filename)
```

I find it is easier to format the string this way to avoid confusion:

```
"entity/{0}.0.{1}.json".format("{{ ds_nodash }}", filename)
```